# SSRS export .txt tabdelimeited format is changing field names

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

SSRS .txt export format is changing my report field name.
Days supply is showing as Days_Supplied
Dispensing is showing as Dispencing
Claim Number is Showing as Amount_Claim_Number

Please suggest, I appreciate your help.

Thank You!

Comment: Ugh - yet another **Microsoft "Feature"** that they refuse to fix. Text exports, for some Bizarro-world reason, use the textbox name of the **data** instead of the text in the table header text box. You can rename the text boxes but you can't use spaces or most punctuation. *To workaround Microsoft's stupidity*, you can add an extra line of data with your header names as your first line and not display the table header at all.

Comment: Thank You @Hannover Fist that was helpful.